# Create nested Category via PHP

Tags: plugin-development, categories

In a custom plugin, I'm able to easily add a new Category:

```php
$category = new CategoryModel();
$category->groupId = 1;
$category->getContent()->title = $categoryName;
craft()->categories->saveCategory($category);
```

That part works great! But for some reason, I can't figure out how to save a **nested** category.

I'd imagine it's something like this, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```php
$childCategory = new CategoryModel();
$childCategory->groupId = 1;
$childCategory->level = 2;
$childCategory->parent = $parentCategory->id;
$childCategory->getContent()->title = $childCategoryName;
craft()->categories->saveCategory($childCategory);
```

Unfortunately that code is giving me an error:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

And if I drop the `->id` portion of this line:

```php
$childCategory->parent = $parentCategory;
```

... it will save the category, but it *won't be nested*.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `$parentCategory` is an existing `CategoryModel` (your error says that `$parentCategory` is not an object):

```
$childCategory = new CategoryModel();
$childCategory->groupId = 1;
$childCategory->newParentId = $parentCategory->id;
$childCategory->getContent()->title = $childCategoryName;

craft()->categories->saveCategory($childCategory);
```

You can see how Craft does it for it's own categories in [CategoriesController->saveCategory()](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/controllers/CategoriesController.php#L360) and [CategoriesService->saveCategory()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/CategoriesService#saveCategory-detail).

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Brad! Curious though... why is it necessary to specify both `newParentId` and `setParent`? Couldn't one be extrapolated from the other?

Comment: That particular chunk of code could probably use some refactoring.

Comment: **Updated:** The relevant Craft code has changed, so the example has been simplified.